# CDROM function - where does the function pointer go to?

Tags: linux, scsi

I am trying to debug an issue where the standard linux CDROMEJECT returns an error even though the disk ejected.

Standard eject command used.

```
ioctl(FP,CDROMEJECT)
```

When I look at the cdrom.c I can see the eject function and the errors (e.g: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/cdrom/cdrom.c#L2303). I am fine with where error codes are returned but you also have lines like this:

```
cdi->ops->lock_door(cdi, 0)
```

Now `lock_door` is a function pointer (see header file [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/cdrom.h#L76)). My issue is I cannot for the life-of-me figure out which function the `lock_door` pointer points to! I would expect this to point to a function that then sends a SCSI command to the CD/DVD drive.

I suspect I am missing some fundamental but really not sure what! Any idea where I find where the function pointers in [struct cdrom_device_ops](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/cdrom.h#L67) point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do an LXR "Freetext Search" for ".lock_door" 
[you can see](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22.lock_door%22+site%3Alxr.free-electrons.com)
it being set for the [scsi driver here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/scsi/sr.c?v=4.0#L126)
and if you click on `sr_lock_door` 
you find it defined in [sr_ioctl.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/scsi/sr_ioctl.c?v=4.0#L286):

```
int sr_lock_door(struct cdrom_device_info *cdi, int lock) {
        Scsi_CD *cd = cdi->handle;
        return scsi_set_medium_removal(cd->device, lock ?
                       SCSI_REMOVAL_PREVENT : SCSI_REMOVAL_ALLOW);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What I do not understand entirely is how are the cdrom.c and the scsi driver (sr.c) related. For example: if I call ioctl(fp,CDROMEJECT), then how is the code in sr.c invoked?

Comment: It is probably the other way around. Your ioctl starts in [sr.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/scsi/sr.c#L542) sr_block_ioctl() which [calls](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/scsi/sr.c#L568)  cdrom_ioctl() which calls cdrom_ioctl_eject() which calls lock_door().  The ops seem to be set [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/scsi/sr.c#L701) at the probe.